# No network activity for WhatsApp messages in fiddler

Tags: android, encryption, whatsapp

I am able to see other HTTPS related activity of apps on the web proxy fiddler, but how is WhatsApp or other end to end encrypted services manage hiding their client to client communications from fiddler and wireshark ?

I do understand few things from the post https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/28030015 but not sure how these things are hidden from network monitors

Is there a visible network activity happening at all behind which I am unable to see due to the poor web proxy configuration ?

Comment: They don't use SSL, instead they use other security protocols.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.